# Double Pointer Usage

Tags: c++, pointers

Please take a look at following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef struct MyType{
int num1;
};

void test(MyType **src)
{
 MyType *ret=new MyType;
 ret->num1=666;
 *src=ret;
}

int main(){
 MyType  *mSrc;
 test(&mSrc);
 printf("%d Address\n",mSrc);
 printf("%d Value \n",mSrc->num1);
}
```

I am wondering if the test() method had been implemented  as follows,why the pointer assignment inside test() method is not visible to the caller?

```
 void test(MyType *src)
    {
     MyType *ret=new MyType;
     ret->num1=666;
     src=ret;     //Why this assignment is only valid inside this method?
    }
```

How do I implement this function without using a double pointer in the signature?

Comment: is it C or C++? if it is C++ as it seems, shouldn't you use `#include <cstdio>`, or rather, use real C++ class/methods to do your output...? I mean, `using` and `iostream` and `new` apart, the rest seems C as your tag... but indeed is C++---

Comment: This is C/C++. It's not as uncommon as some people think, offering the expressive power of C, the simplicity of C++, and guaranteed employment for maintenance programmers.

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  void test(MyType *src)
```

Here `src` is just a local variable within the `test` function, it's a copy of the pointer you passed to it.  Assigning to a local variable doesn't have any effect on the caller.

If you wanted `src` to refer to the same variable you passed in, use a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B))

```
void test(MyType *&src)
```

Comment: when I use *& compiler gives the error :
 "error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token"

Comment: Perhaps you're compiling it as C, not C++,or you mistyped something

Answer (score 4):

because you pass a copy of src pointer and you only modify the copy inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Because the **value** that is passed with `src` is the address where the pointer points to. If you change it, it is only changed inside the function.

It is the same thing as if you would pass an integer and change its value. The value is only changed inside the function.

In C, everything is [**call by value**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value#Call_by_value), that is why we have "special" values (but they are still values), that can point to some location.